# Semaphore not initialising on init line

Tags: c, semaphore

Hi I am trying to use semaphores but I get the error message, /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccZPMKb.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sem_init@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

my code is

```
sem_t* mutex;
sMutex = shm_open("mutex", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(sMutex, sizeof(sem_t*));
mutex = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t*), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sMutex, 0);
sem_init(mutex, 1, 1); //Without this line it compiles
```

I am compiling using:

```
gcc testSem.c -ltr
```

And I have included semaphore.h

Comment: I had to use shared memory because I am also using processes in my code

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you passing a semaphore descriptor to [`ftruncate`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html), a function which "truncates" *files*?

Comment: shm_open creates the shared memory, ftruncate configures the size of the shared memory, and mmap maps the shared memory to address of sMutex

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and not sure if I'm missing something to install?

Comment: Or could be my code is wrong

Comment: `-ltr` -> `-lrt`

Comment: And don't forget to add error checking. Always have error checking.

Comment: And by the way, `sizeof(sem_t*)` doesn't have to be the same size as `sizeof(sem_t)`.  Think about what you want to create the shared memory for, a pointer to an object, or the object itself.